# jquery - binding plugin/event to a dynamically loaded element

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, plugins, bind

i use the tooltip plugin of jquerytools (http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tooltip/index.html).
I don't understand how to bind it to a dynamically loaded element.

The 'normal' way i use it is:

```
$(".myElementClass").tooltip({ 
  effect: 'slide',
  tip: '#myTipId',
  offset: [40, 0],
  relative: true,
  position: 'top center'
})
```

But if .myElementClass is loaded by ajax this won't work.
In dynamically loaded elements i use the 'on' sintax like this:

```
$(document).on("hover", ".myElement",function(){
  ...do something ...     
})
```

How should I mix the two things?

**Edit After tristan correct answer:**

```
$(document).on("hover", ".myElementClass",function(){
    tooltip=$(this).tooltip({
            effect: 'slide',
            tip: '#myTipId',
            offset: [40, 0],
            relative: true,
            position: 'top center',
            api:true
        });
        tooltip.show();
    })
```

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Is tooltip permits to declare a tooltip function or call the tooltip for displaying?

Comment: @AspiringAqib: jQuery v1.7.1 bundled with jquerytools v1.2.7

Comment: @sdespont: don't know :-(

Comment: Do you have an error in console (F12)?

Comment: Try getting the latest version of both [jQuery 1.8.3] and also of jquery tools. and as @sdespont said have you any error in console? if you are using chrome then right click and select "Inspect Element" and select "Console". See the errors there. If there will be no error then there will be no text otherwise will have text. `Right Click > Inspect Element > Console`.

Comment: see my answer :D hope it helps :>

Comment: @AspiringAqib: same result with latest version of libraries.

Comment: nah i added answer with some setTimeout check that whether it works :D

Comment: worked or not? I have to remove it because i think it will not :/

Comment: No, doesn't work. thanks for trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
     $("input[type=button]").click(function() {
        $(".output").append("<div class='added' style='background-color:red;'>Hover Me , You will get tooltip</div>");
     });
     var tooltip = null;
     $(".output").on("hover", ".added", function () {
        if (tooltip == null) {
           tooltip = $(this).tooltip({
              effect: "slide",
              tip: "#myTipId",
              offset: [40, 0],
              relative: true,
              position: "top center",
              api:true
           });
        }
        tooltip.show();
     });
  });
```

```
<body>
   <div id="myTipId" style="display:none;">I'm tooltip</div>
   <input type="button" value="Add new Item" />
   <div class="output" style="border:1px solid black;"></div>
</body>
```

---

Explanation: set **config.api = true**. If that, fn.tooltip(conf) will return tooktip object rather than the target HTML element itself. Refer to the source code https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js #352